# SelectByVisibleText method failing

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

`selectByVisibleText()` method seem to fail while selecting the text from the drop down.

During execution the drop down seem to function fine and the cursor scrolls over the required text, but fails to pick it up. used to function fine before.. no idea as to what is causing this problem...

Tried code. :-

```
public void selectByVisibleText(By by,String text) {   
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100); 
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by)); 
 Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(by)); 
 select.selectByVisibleText(text);
}

utils.selectByVisibleText(By.id(""),"Text");
```

any help much appreciated!!

Comment: Did you tried other methods such as `.selectByIndex()` or `.selectByValue()`?? And share dropdown HTML as well..

Comment: Tried .selectByValue() Saurab, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code in my **utils** and it works fine.

Comment: Cheers mate, it seems to be work for me too but fails at times. I used thread.sleep() in the method and it seems to behave ok , well for the moment at least. Need to investigate Further though.